# How to use 'end' keyword argument with print function?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and I tried to print the statement in python from the text file. I used the following code and It is throwing me syntax errors from the `print` statements. I am not sure figure out.

```
file= (test.txt)
with open (file) as f:
    l=f.readline()
    print (l[10:19], end = "");
    print (l[20:34], end = "");
    print (l[40:45], end = "");
```

since I need multiple words from different locations (a few words from the same line and a few words from different lines). I used multiple `print` statements.

Please suggest me if there are any possible best solutions to print multiple words from different locations.

Comment: You should post your errors. `file= (test.txt)` - did you really mean `file = "test.txt"`. String literals are bound by `'` or `"` not parens.

Comment: Skip `;` - you do not need it here

Comment: You've tagged both versions of python but which is it?

Comment: change ``file= (test.txt)`` to ``file = 'text.txt'``, here open takes input which either a text or byte string not tuple.

Comment: Also your prints will give you all the same characters from each line, is this desired behaviour? You can post your input file somewhere and expected output, easier fix your example then.

Comment: I guess you are on Python 2. Python 2 supports (by lucky accidents) most of the print function syntax of Python 3. What it not working are keyword arguments like `end`.

Comment: The `end=` keyword argument is only supported in Python 3.x and the `print()` ***function*** — in Python 2.x, `print` is a ***statement*** and works differently. What version of Python are you using? Please tag your question according.

Comment: Thank you @Achampion I figured this

Comment: Thank you @ Evgency. But it worked with  or without  ';'

Comment: @ roganjosh will do that next time. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @ Sushanth. I got it

Comment: @Evgency actually No I do not want the same Index position from each line. For instance, From the first line, I want 2nd words 5th word and 7th word and from second-line, I need 2nd word, 6th word, and 10th word likewise different random words from every line. I don't think I have written my code like this. Can you please suggest me how it works

Comment: Thank you @klaus D

Comment: Thank you @martineau. Sure Ill do it from next time.

Answer (score 0):

First error
You should have used string with single or double quote. You just wrote `file=(test.txt)`, which should be replaced with `file='test.txt'`.

The next one is semicolon(`;`) at the end of the line within your for loop clause.
So use the following

```
print (l[10:19], end="")
print (l[20:34], end="")
print (l[40:45], end="")
```

I hope this would help you even a little bit.

Comment: I figured it out Thank you @Jacob